# Can't able to acces root in regedit

Tags: regex, perl, registry, registrykey

I want to validate xmlfile using my exe. so i want to set the argument and calling exe path in registry.

the below code cannot locate the registry path it dies when i executed.

i cannot able get progid from registery userchoice.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32;
use File::Basename;
use Win32::TieRegistry(Delimiter=>"/");
my $reg,$tmval;
$reg = $Registry->Open("HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/FileExts/.xml/UserChoice") or die;
        ($tmval) = $reg->GetValue('Progid');
        if(defined($tmval) and $tmval ne "") {
            # Parse .xml
                $reg=$Registry->Open("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/$tmval/shell") or die;
                $reg=$reg->CreateKey( "XMLValidate" );
                $reg=$reg->CreateKey( "command");
                # $reg=$reg->SetValue( "","\"C:\\itools\\ePUB-Conversion\\ePUB_PopupSupport.exe\" \"\%1\" \"P\"","REG_SZ");
                $reg=$reg->SetValue( "","\"calling exe\" \"\%1\"","REG_SZ");
        }
        else {
            if(!defined($tmval)){$tmval = "xmlfile";}
            $reg=$Registry->Open("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT") or die;
            $reg=$reg->CreateKey( "$tmval" );
            $reg=$reg->CreateKey( "shell");
            $reg=$reg->CreateKey( "XMLValidate" );
            $reg=$reg->CreateKey( "command");
            # $reg=$reg->SetValue( "","\"C:\\itools\\ePUB-Conversion\\ePUB_PopupSupport.exe\" \"\%1\" \"P\"","REG_SZ");
            $reg=$reg->SetValue( "","\"calling exe" \"\%1\"","REG_SZ");
        }
```

please help thanks advance.

Comment: `it dies`. Without a error message and any indication what's wrong? Try to debug to get closer to the root of the problem.

Comment: Now working access permission is the problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now working access permission is the problem thanks. –  Deepankumar